# I am using Visual Studio and I have a SQL Server table, but when I insert data, I get an error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server table, but it is not allowing me to do so and throws an error. I think the error is from the role I don't know how to fix it; please I need your help - thank you.

This is the member table that I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member] 
(
     [Member_Username] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     [Password]        NVARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
     [Role]            NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
     [FirstName]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     [LastName]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
     [Gender]          NVARCHAR (8)  NOT NULL,
     [Email]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
     [DateOfBirth]     DATE          NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Member_Username] ASC)
);
```

And this is the error I get when inserting the values into the table:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   The parameterized query '(@memberU nvarchar(1), @pwd nvarchar(1), @role nvarchar(4000), @fna' expects the parameter '@role', which was not supplied.

This is the member class that I have for inserting the user in the database table:

```
public void AddMember()
{
    // Open database connection
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = Config.GetConnectionStr();
    conn.Open();

    // Prepare SQL command with parameters
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Member VALUES (@memberU, @pwd, @role, @fname, @lname, @gender, @email, @dob)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("memberU", this.Member_Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pwd", this.Password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("role", this.Role);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", this.FirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", this.LastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", this.Email);

    // handling null values for gender and date of birth column
    if (this.Gender != null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", this.Gender);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gender", DBNull.Value);
    }

    if (this.DateofBirth != null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", this.DateofBirth);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", DBNull.Value);
    }

    // Execute command
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And this is the sign up button:

```
protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Page.IsValid)// assuming you have done validations using validation controls
        {// c create a new object of type member and set all it's properties to values from controls
            Members user = new Members();
            //reading required values
            user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            user.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
            user.Member_Username = txtUserName.Text;
            user.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            user.Gender = rdoGender.SelectedValue;

            //reading values that allow null in the database (date of birth)
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDOB.Text))
            {
                user.DateofBirth = null;

            }
            else
            {
                user.DateofBirth = DateTime.Parse(txtDOB.Text);
            }

            //call the addMember method
            user.AddMember();

            //redirect the user to homePage
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  All your posts have a score of 0 or less which will cause trouble for you soon.

Comment: You are never assigning anything to `user.Role` hence the value is `null` and fails

Comment: In `SignUp` Method, assign a value for `user.Role`.

Comment: What does this have to do with html? And indeed MySql since it looks like you're using Sql Several? Please only add appropriate tags.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

can you try when you add parameters like ( cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@role",value).